# How do you add custom HTTP headers to Chrome Custom Tabs?

Tags: java, android, chrome-custom-tabs

With standard Android WebViews, you use `WebView.loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders)`. How do you add your additional headers with Chrome Custom Tabs?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can send headers or anything related to the http request besides the url. I hope future versions will allow sending headers in `Bundle` when you establish `CustomTabSession` or so.

Entire http call is [managed in `CustomTabActivity`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/customtabs/CustomTabActivity.java).

**Edit:**

As of recent updates of the library, you can now add `Bundle` and pass it to the `CustomTabsIntent` intent as extra with key `Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS`

```
Bundle headers = new Bundle();
headers.putString("header1", "value1");
headers.putString("header2", "value2");
customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, headers);
```

Comment: I want to specify a "Cookie" in my header. I tried doing `headers.putString("Cookie", sessionID);`. But when I inspect the request, it looks like maybe Chrome Custom Tabs overwrite my "Cookie" header with their own. Do you know if Chrome Custom Tabs overwrite the "Cookie" header?

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski  Sir I was trying to pass header using the above code mentioned by you but its not working please help how I am gonna rectify the problem.

Comment: This seems to have stopped working with the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: according to this article you can do this but it requires setting up Digital Asset Links: https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs/headers#set_up_a_custom_tabs_connection_to_validate_the_asset_link

Comment: `"The name of the extra data in the VIEW intent. The data are key/value pairs in the format of Bundle. They will be sent in the HTTP request headers for the provided url. The keys can't be the standard HTTP headers as they are set by the WebView. The url's schema must be http(s)."`

For the documentation regarding `EXTRA_HEADERS`.

Answer (score 1):

The above mentions solutions won't work for new version of `ChromeTab`.Please follow this link [fix](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/tree/master/demos/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsdemos) for work around.You can also study the medium post by [Romain Piel](https://medium.com/@_rpiel/chrome-custom-tabs-and-headers-or-a-happy-open-source-story-9c3f82680eea) which implicitly states the usage and the work around for adding headers.

Comment: Neither of those links offer any solution that was not already mentioned above.

Comment: Well i think there is'nt any work around for this because there seems to be a  bug with chrometabs which implicitly states that there was a change in there version of chrometab after 13th Oct which states that they are using a wrong function of dispatch headers which only allows only on header to be added and ignores the headers when we add more than one headers and starts using its own conventional headers by overwriting the existing .Please follow this link ..https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=772966

Comment: @DRYBeliever although your comments are true, your solution suggests there's a workaround, but neither link provides one.  Please edit your answer to reflect this fact.